# $x\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$, s.t. $x^2=p+q\sqrt{30}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Does there exists $x\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ of the form
$$
x=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{5}+e\sqrt{6}+f\sqrt{10}+g\sqrt{15}+h\sqrt{30},\tag{1}
$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h\in\mathbb{Q}$,
such that 
$$
x^2 = p+q\sqrt{30}, \qquad p,q\in\mathbb{Q},\tag{2}
$$
but with one restriction:
**at least three** of values $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ are **non-zero**?

---

There are quite obvious $x$-solutions for one and two terms in $(1)$:

$(\sqrt{5})^2=5+0\sqrt{30}$,
$(1+\sqrt{30})^2=31+2\sqrt{30}$,

$(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{10})^2=13+2\sqrt{30}$,

but how about three and more terms?